# This function to calculate the area of a rectangle is not veryreadable

Tags: python-3.x

This function to calculate the area of a rectangle is not very readable. Can you refactor it, and then call the function to calculate the area with base of 5 and height of 6? Tip: a function that calculates the area of a rectangle should probably be called `rectangle_area`, and if it's receiving base and height, that's what the parameters should be called.

```
def f1(x, y):

z = x*y # the area is base*height

print("The area is " + str(z))
```

My Error:

```
def rectangle_area (x, y):
   area = 5*6 # the area is base*height
   print("The area is " + str(area))
```

(Python) - Code Style

Comment: `area = x * y` It should also probably `return area` since it is called `rectangle_area` and not `print_rectangle_area`. Later in the program call it with `print("The area is " + rectangle_area(5, 6))`

Answer (score 2):

**The Answer:**

```
def rectangle_area(base, height): 
    area = base*height 
    print("The area is " + str(area)) 

rectangle_area(5,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Accurate Answer :**

> given by the question base =5 and height=6

**Python code Style :-**

```
def rectangle_area(base,height):
    area = base*height   # the area is base*height
    print(f"The area is :{str(area)}") 
rectangle_area(5,6)
```

**Output :-**

```
The area is : 30
```

Answer (score 0):

def rectangle_area(base, height):

```
area = base * height
print("The area is "+ str(area))
```

rectangle_area(5,6)

Answer (score -3):

The code will be:

```
def rectangle_area(base,height):
    area = base*height
    return area
base = float(input("Enter the base length of the rectangle : "))
height = float(input("Enter the height of the rectangle : "))
print("The area is ",rectangle_area(base,height))
```

Then the output will be:

```
Enter the base length of the rectangle : 5
Enter the height of the rectangle : 6
The area is  30.0
```

Comment: @RedowanDelowar, I can only guess, but probably because this is a ["gimme teh codez"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question) type of question, which should have been closed & removed instead of being answered with a code-only answer like this.